# Python: How can I open a folder with variable

Tags: python-2.7

question again... I have a list `A=['AA','BB','CC']` and  a folder path like `./ABC/`. There are three sub folder inside called `032_AA, 0244_BB, 01_CC`
format is like `random number_AA(BB or CC)`.

now I tend to use this list to enter these folder and open a txt file which in there sub folder:

```
cmd1='cd ABC'
os.sys(cmd1)
for i in A:
    ???????? ---------------------- enter folder 032_AA according to list A
    with open('xxx.txt','a') as f:
    XXXXXXXX
```

my main question is I dont know how to enter a folder with a known file name with random number as begining.
So any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You could use os.walk to find all the folders in the current directory, then filter on the last 2 letters being equal to e.g. AA and then go to that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use glob:

```
    import glob 
    regex = './ABC/*'
    for i in A:
      subdir = regex + i
      for name in glob.glob(subdir):
```

U can check [glob](https://pymotw.com/2/glob/) for more info on pattern matching

Comment: other question is how to add variable in  `for name in glob.glob('dir/*_AA'):`   like I wana use loop (for x in A:)on my list to replace `*_AA` to `*_x`??

Comment: u can use string concat with the pattern. i edited my answer to give the solution